# Max function in python returning wrong results

Tags: python, max

I am trying to find the Max and Min in a set of numbers from a CSV file. My code keeps returning the wrong number for Max function for some rows. Here is my code:

```
with open('Cortex_vs_Liver_trial.csv', newline='') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        print('The maximun is:', max(row))
        print('The minimum is:', min(row))
```

An example of my output:

```
['86.21', '100.00', '96.30']
The maximun is: 96.30
The minimum is: 100.00
```

I am not sure what I have done wrong. Some advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You're comparing strings not numeric data.  Use: `max (col[3:6], key=float)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your list elements are strings. You need to convert them to `float` to avoid comparing lexicographically (alphabetically, one character at a time, where `'100' < '2'` because `1 < 2`)

```
numrow = [float(x) for x in row]
print('The maximun is:', max(numrow))
print('The minimum is:', min(numrow))
```

Unless you actually want strings, in which case don't make the new list, and just pass `key=float` to your `max()` function:

```
max(numrow, key=float)
```